# Tablix (table) in SSRS 2012 not allowing CanGrow=false on tablix cells

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

[image: Report, tablix cell expand]
I am facing a very weird problem while creating a report in SSRS (I am using  sql server 2012 enterprise edition).

This is the structure of my report:

- Report columns are in Page Header section, not in  tablix header. (I
  had to  remove report columns from tablix header because I needed my
  report to freeze it's header or its column after exporting to excel.
  This freezing in excel could be done only when columns are in Page
  Header)
- Tablix has fields with several groupings.

Now what happens, when I run the report and if any field having a larger string value than the size of tablix cell, it grows badly in width. That makes my report looks  ugly. Columns in page header are not aligned with  their rows in tablix. Tablix  goes out of the report actual width .

For getting rid of this problem, I tried making  `CanGrow=false`  of every cell in tablix. I then tried deploying the report, but failed. I got an  error: `"Report definition is invalid"`.

The  problem is, I can't set `CanGrow=false` to cells in tablix then how would my report remain  stable. How would my columns be  aligned with the data in tablix.

I just  do not want the cells to grow in width that they are doing right now.

Attaching a screen shot of the report I saw when  I have a larger value in  a cell. This value is a whole word.

Please help me out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Post your image to SO. Just edit your post and click on add an image. Have you tried setting the size of the column?

Comment: @eestein Thanks for replying. Just edited post. Yes, column size is already defined, but the CanGrow property of cells couldn't set.

Comment: Ok, now I see your image. That indeed is a very strange problem. Can you post a picture of your report desing? Also select a column, press F4 and see if the can grow property is set.